# Rails 4 Formtastic action label escaping

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, formtastic, html-safe

Does anyone know how to add a glyphicon to a formtastic submit button label? It seems that no matter what I do, the string is always escaped

The current snippet I have is:

```
<%= f.action :submit, label: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk'></span> Save".html_safe, button_html: { class: 'btn btn-primary' } %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I wound up just using a plain old submit button in the following format:

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-primary') do %>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk'></span> Save
<% end %>
```

If anyone else has a better way of accomplishing this I'm all ears